# MYSQL PHP Application performance with single database

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance, database-performance

I am designing an "high" traffic application which realies mainly on PHP and MySQL database queries.

I am designing the database tables so they can hold 100'000 rows, each page loading queries the db for user data.

I can experience slow performances or database errors when there are say 1000 users connected ?

Asking because i cannot find specification on the real performance limits of mysql databases.

Thanks

Comment: method one. use stored procedures for little faster and secure.

Comment: You should use caching for reducing the stress on you DB-server, and of course you should profile your code, and see what queries are making a biggest hit on perfomance, and optimize them as much as possible.

When you think you're done you might also want to try out stress-testing through some sites like http://loadimpact.com/

Comment: Different server for webserver and databse is a good idea.

Comment: @GabrielSantos Yes that's a more secure architecture. But if he uses a thirdparty hoster it will be difficult to setup the mysql server for external connections.

Comment: For a good answer please be more specific: What is high load, which queries are you running, what kind of data do you need etc. Don't even think about performance yet, first structure the data well. Just use the normal forms. Finally you can always add performance but keep your data as well-structured as possible from the beginning. Spend time on performance when it is needed, for example when you see it becomes important after measurements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the userdata remains unchanged due loading another page, you could think about storing those information in a session.
Also, you should analyze how the read/write ratio in your database/ on specific tables is. MyIsam and InnoDB are very different when it comes to locking. Many connections can slow down your server, try to cache connections.

Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Answer (score 0):

if designed wrongly, one user might kill your server. you need to have performance tests, find bottle necks profiling your code. use explain for your queries...

Answer (score 0):

Well designed databases can handle with tens of millions of rows, but poor designed can't.
Don't worry about performance, try to design it well.

Answer (score 0):

It's just hard to say a design was good or not,you should always do some stress tests before you set up your application or website to help you see the performance,tools i often used were mysqlslap(for mysql only) and apache's ab command.you can google them for details.